# GL ARB Shadow Ambient Extension is not supported

Tags: lwjgl, shadows, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to build a game engine with LWJGL under Java.
I'm want to implement Shadowmapping, but I'm stuck with the tutorials from Oskar Veehoek ([here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiqiCVs3R4Q&list=UUxiBXBY1a-axNVGIvQKGcNA), specifcally).  When I try to use the shadow mapping OpenGL extension, I get the error:

> GL ARB Shadow Ambient Extension is not supported

What might be the source of this problem?

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial? ARB is the OpenGL Architecture Review Board, who check over proposals to the OpenGL standards. I'm pretty sure the tutorials are referring to [this extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shadow.txt). (I just Googled all of that. You should try it too.) Does that help?

Comment: Yes ,here is the Link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiqiCVs3R4Q&list=UUxiBXBY1a-axNVGIvQKGcNA but what do I have to do with the file you directed to see it work? Thanks,Mineorbit

Comment: The file I linked is just a status document for the shadow mapping OpenGL extension. (It's not code.) Oskar's code is on github, linked from the video description. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes ,I know that but if I run the code, than i get the error that the GL ARB Shadow Ambient Extension is not supported, how can I fix that? Thanks, Mineorbit!

Comment: Please edit the question to include that error you're getting. (At the moment, the question reads like you're expecting us to write your code for you.)

Comment: Thanks very much im gonna look at the resource! i don't want you to write my code, I just don't get it what extensions are and why i Need them!

Comment: For those who scroll above this site and have the same Problem as I had, the Problem was that nVidia Graphicscrad do not love FBO so you have to revamp this part and the Problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the shadow mapping tutorials at [this site](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/). Another great tutorial can be found [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/).

I managed to implement shadow mapping for my LWJGL game without using any extensions and using only these two tutorials. The code can be transferred to Java pretty easily.

As far as i know, if you are using C++, only OpenGL 1.1 is guaranteed. Anything else needs to be loaded manually from extensions. LWJGL does this for you. You can find the corresponding functions in the GL30 etc. namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments by the OP, this was the problem:

> nVidia Graphicscrad do not love FBO so you have to revamp this part and the Problem is solved!